# Loop nested PHP array, shorter than parent

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

Ok, so I have two arrays – one for posts, and a limited array of 5 values for the colors to give each post. What I want is for the posts to cycle through the array of colors, so that every 6th starts over. What I'm doing now works per se with a limited number of posts, but it's kind of hacky not very elegant:

```
$colors = array('yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple');

foreach($posts as $i => $post) {
  $color = $colors[$i];
  if ($i >= count($colors)) {
    $color = $colors[-count($colors) + $i];
    if ($i >= (count($colors) * 2)) {
      $color = $colors[(-count($colors) * 2) + $i];
    }
  }
//Do stuff here
}
```

I'm sure there's a smarter way to do this, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulus 5 (%5) will do the quick fix

```
for($i=0;$i<count($posts);$i++){
   $color=$colors[$i%5];
   # todo here
}
```

Comment: and then count($colors) instead of 5

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: @ruud that is making the program heavier, we already know the number

Comment: ok, but if the color array is changed, then the number must also be changed. Better to have a program that always works then to have a lighter program that is vulnerable to this kind of bugs.